# get PID of QProcess with python on windows

Tags: python, qt4, pyqt, qprocess

Is there some way to read the PID of a process started with QProcess.start(...)? `QProcess::pid()` returns `sip.voidptr` and there's not much I can do with it (or I don't know how).

I want to have the PID to have the possibility to make the window active later on.

Answer (score 2):

Try [`QProcess.startDetached`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qprocess.html#startDetached) since it spawns a standalone process, removing the possibility of sharing PID with its parent.

[This](http://ftp.ics.uci.edu/pub/centos0/ics-custom-build/BUILD/sip-4.10/doc/html/python_api.html) might provide some you further insight.

Comment: I know that startDetached returns pid of new process... but is there possibility of  catch finished() signal?

Also... it is a separate process anyway... so I don't get why it is not simplified?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
proc = QtCore.QProcess().start(cmdOrWhaterver)
pid = int(proc.pid())
```

Not sure if this helps you or not but you can also try `proc.setObjectName()` which has worked for me when referencing a process after it has run for a bit.

that's for python anyway

Answer (score 0):

pid() function is provided to keep old source code working.
Use processId() instead.
Returns the native process identifier for the running process, if available. If no process is currently running, 0 is returned.
Note: Unlike processId(), pid() returns an integer on Unix and a pointer on Windows.